# Unexpected reset of the daily login count (towards Enthusiast badge)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, participation, badges

I am logging into the site everyday, for the "Enthusiast", without fail. However today the login count was reset from 22 to 1 ! What should I do?

**EDIT**
While going through the activity log and votes log I found another bug where the number of votes is different in the same profile.

[image: Vote Count Error]

Comment: Are you tracking your days according to GMT?  (Local time is irrelevant for this badge.)

Comment: Yes, with GMT tracking, still count got reset

Comment: Your record shows little activity on our site.  Although the details of what kinds of activity qualify for this badge are not publicly known, it is known that merely logging in does not count as being active on the site.  The point of this badge is to encourage people into constructive interaction: editing, voting, commenting, asking, answering.  If you do those, the badges will take care of themselves.

Comment: @whuber I understand what you are saying in the spirit of badge, but in the letter there is a bug which causes the reset, there is some programming bug, some data corruption, that needs to be taken care of...

Comment: I'm not seeing any evidence of such a bug.  As I wrote above, I find very little evidence of any activity by you on our main site.  I'm surprised you actually got up to 22 days.

Comment: @whuber I am not sure what kind of evidence you are looking for here. Should I have 21 different questions asked on consecutive days to provide evidence ? If you want to ignore the bug its all right.

Comment: I am not advocating ignoring a bug--I'm just saying there's nothing here anyone can take any action about, because there's no evidence of any bug at all: http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/12065/sarvex?tab=activity.  (As a moderator I have access to far more detailed information than that--but it doesn't show anything more.)

Comment: These are my votes http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/12065/sarvex?tab=votes They show a regular activity apart for April 3 which is counted as missed

Comment: It looks like this is [status-bydesign], as @whuber said.

Comment: Might want to consider posting the votes issue as a separate bug report. It is probably just a caching issue, but still better to report two separate issues in two separate posts nevertheless.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not a bug, but I hope this answer can help you narrowing down your issue.

First of all, one needs to understand what is a 'day' in Stack Exchange and realize that badges like Enthusiast and Fanatic are awarded based on it. See:

[What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)

Basically, a day starts at 0 hour from UTC time. Then, one can check which days the system counted as visited ([remembering that just logging in does not count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21897/is-there-a-minimum-level-of-activity-required-to-get-the-enthusiast-badge/67546#67546)):

Just go to the user tab [profile](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/12065/sarvex?tab=profile) and click on link `visited x days, y consecutive` to see if any 'day' was missed. For example, I missed day 15th in March, here in CV Meta :(.

If it is the case you haven't missed any day, and this is indeed a bug, I suggest you to post a question in the main [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site. Link to this question there for providing some introduction.

[image]

Comment: I suggest linking to this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485 and possibly even quoting from it here, because this seems to be the main point of confusion.